# How to set font in decimal number using HSSFFont

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to set text font to 7.5 to a particular text in excel sheet. I am using below code to prepare the Font.

```
HSSFCellStyle txtStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)workbook.createCellStyle();
HSSFFont txtFont = (HSSFFont)workbook.createFont();
txtFont.setFontName("Arial");
txtFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)7.5);
txtStyle.setFont(txtFont);
```

But it always takes font as 7 because of short type casting and hence targeted text in excel sheet is taking font 7 and not 7.5. I also tried method 'setFontHeight' but that also takes short as parameter. So is there any way by which I could set text font to decimal number?

Comment: Does Excel support font sizes like 7.5, or does it round too?

Comment: Yes. MS Excel supports font size 7.5. It doesn't comes in standard font size drop down in toolbar but once we select any font size from that drop down we can manually edit and change that font size to decimal number and hit enter. The changed font gets applied. Similar I am trying to do the same using POI.

Comment: If you create a file with a font size of 7.5 in Excel, then read that back in Apache POI, what font size does POI see for it? (Try both [getFontHeight()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#getFontHeight%28%29) and [getFontHeightInPoints()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#getFontHeightInPoints%28%29))

Comment: After reading xls file where font size was manually set to 7.5, getFontHeight gives 150 and getFontHeightInPoints gives 7. So as a reverse engineering, I did   txtFont.setFontHeight((short)150) and it worked !! The generated excel shows font size 7.5. Thanks @Gagravarr for the hint !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Promoting comments to an answer - the POI HSSF Font class has two font size settings methods:

- [setFontHeight(short)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#setFontHeight%28short%29) - Set the font height in unit's of 1/20th of a point
- [setFontHeightInPoints(short)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#setFontHeightInPoints%28short%29) - Set the font height in point

Using [setFontHeightInPoints](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#setFontHeightInPoints%28short%29) is the easier one for most cases, and is recommended in the Javadocs. However, it'll only cope with whole-number font heights. That's most font sizes, but not all

To set a font height of 7.5, you'd need to change your code instead to be:

```
xtFont.setFontHeight((short)(7.5*20));
```

That uses the alternate one that takes `1/20` point sizes, so copes with non-integer values.